# How to loop over multiple ids from a text file to get an API URL?

Tags: python

I am newbie to python.Here is what i am trying to do.

- I have a api (https://abcd.com/MACHINES/)
- I have a list of machine names in a text file(mylist.txt)
  mylist.txt:
  1234
  2356
  7879
- I need to pass each machine name from the textfile(mylist.txt) to hit the api and capture response and store it to a file.
  example:
  https://abcd.com/MACHINES/1234
- Response i will get from the API is XML and large response(200 lines) for each machine.

## Here is my working code for a Single Machine with hardcoded machine name(1234):

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = "https://abcd.com/MACHINES/1234"
user = "xxxxx"
passwd = "xxxxx"

auth_values = (user, passwd)

response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_values)

with open('allmachineresponses.xml', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

- When I am trying to loop with the mylist.txt file i am getting 404 error and no responses.

## Error Code:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('mylist.txt') as f_input:
    for ids in f_input:
        url = "https://abcd.com/MACHINES/{0}".format( ids )
        user = "XXXX"
        passwd = "XXXX"
        auth_values = (user, passwd)
        response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_values)
        print response.content
```

Could you please help me to correct my code and store all 
 responses to a single file

Comment: Change f_input in your for loop to f_input.read().split()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
url = "https://abcd.com/MACHINES/{0}".format( ids )
```

Should be like this:

```
url = "https://abcd.com/MACHINES/{0}".format(ids.strip())
```

This removes any newlines or spaces from the `ids` <=> machine name.

It might be better to read the whole file to memory first, close it, and only then loop over it, thus minimizing the time you have to keep the file reference open. You could do it like this:

```
with open('mylist.txt') as f_input:
    lines = f_input.readlines()

for ids in lines:
    url = "https://abcd.com/MACHINES/{0}".format(ids.strip())
    user = "XXXX"
    passwd = "XXXX"
    auth_values = (user, passwd)
    response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_values)
    print response.content
```